# Rendering an action with :notice that depends on a URL param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an action 'approval' that renders a view which displays some content from a Model (class). Within the view I have a link_to that calls `accept` with a URL parameter (:id). After the `accept` action completes (sets approve to true) I would like to render `approval` again with a message ("Saved!"). However, unlike a static login page, the approval action requires a param the first time it is called. The second time it is rendered, an runtime error occurs (obviously). What is the best way to call `approval` with the flash notice?

```
def approval
  @c = Class.find(params[:id])
end


def accept
  @c = Class.find(params[:id])
  @c.approve = true
  @c.save

  render 'approval', :notice => "Saved!"
end
```

Comment: Runtime error occurred due to id is not passed to find @c in second time. So you can pass id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change this `render 'approval', :notice => "Saved!"` to

```
flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: :back - Back to the page that issued the request. Useful for forms that are triggered from multiple places. Short-hand for redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FlashHash#now` to set the notice for the current action

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Saved !'
render 'approval'
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now

Answer (score 2):

Exceprt from: http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/adding-flash-message-capability-to-your-render-calls-in-rails

Now the common pattern in controllers looks like this:

```
if @foo.save
  redirect_to foos_path, :notice => "Foo saved"
else
  flash[:alert] = "Some errors occured"
  render :action => :new
end
```

What I want to be able to do is this:

```
if @foo.save
  redirect_to foos_path, :notice => "Foo saved"
else
  render :action => :new, :alert => "Some errors occured"
end
```

Adding this functionality is actually pretty simple – we just have to create some code extending the render function.
This next piece of code actually extends the module containing the functionality for the redirect calls.

```
module ActionController
  module Flash

    def render(*args)
      options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.last : {}

      if alert = options.delete(:alert)
        flash[:alert] = alert
      end

      if notice = options.delete(:notice)
        flash[:notice] = notice
      end

      if other = options.delete(:flash)
        flash.update(other)
      end

      super(*args)
    end

  end
end
```